# SSRS Grouping with multiple columns

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

I have a SQL table called 'Voucher'

[image]

The resulting report must look like this:

[image]

**Design Considerations:**
Report must Group by Name,
then group by VoucherType and be sorted by Date

Please can someone help me with steps on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In below Image left hand side is original table and right hand side is your desired result,

[image]

How did I achieved this?

First Parent Group by Name and then Child group by Vourcher Type

[image]

Here is grouping details for you.

[image]